# Display a (view) block for everyone except one role

Tags: views, blocks

I have a block which has been generated by a view, and would like to show this block to all users except people who have been granted a particular role, is this possible, and if so how, exactly?

Many thanks in advance.

-Sniper

Comment: this http://drupal.org/project/deny_access is the kind of thing i'm looking for, however it does not yet provide functionality to block per content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Blocks Admin page, you can use PHP to display/not display the block, so you could put something like this in there:

```
<?php

global $user;

if (in_array('ROLETHATSHOULDNOTSEETHISBLOCK',array_values($user->roles))) {
  return FALSE;
} else {
  return TRUE;
}

?>
```

OR just check all the roles BUT the ROLETHATSHOULDNOTSEETHISBLOCK in the other part of the form :)

ADDITION:

With respect to PHP and security, I presume JoeS is referring to these paragraphs within **The Definitive Guide to Drupal 7**...

**Avoid Using the PHP Filter Module**

Although it’s handy to be able to write PHP code directly into your Drupal web interface without having to create a module, it’s also very dangerous! All PHP code should live in the form of modules or themes. Writing PHP in Drupal’s web interface is a bad idea for the following reasons:

• It’s unfriendly to edit and debug (no syntax highlighting and no proper error reporting).

• It makes code reviews difficult and versioning impossible.

• A trusted user might inadvertently damage your site with malformed PHP code.
• If your site was to be compromised, a hacker could penetrate and damage your server using well-crafted PHP code. Keeping the PHP Filter module turned off (or even better, removing it entirely from the filesystem) could help contain such intrusion to the Drupal level only.

• In terms of performance, storing PHP code in the database will prevent any opcode caching mechanism from working on this piece of code

Note that some contributed modules might offer a functionality similar to that of the PHP Filter module; they will suffer from the same flaws noted previously.

```
                                   **and**
```

■ Tip If the PHP Filter module is enabled, try to disable it. PHP Filter module should not be used to provide functionality on node (content) pages. Avoiding that is a good idea from both code quality and deployment perspectives. For placing functionality, rather than content, on a page or part of a page, use Drupal’s hook_menu(), hook_block(), or hook_page_build().

...which refer to the PHP Filter Module, not the admin interface.  This module allows users to enter PHP code into a node directly and I wholeheartedly agree that this opens far too many doors.

However, in this case, I am talking about using an option given to the administrator of a site by the drupal admin interface, one that hopefully is used by someone with far more PHP experience than casual users of the system.

Furthermore, using this option is most probably a one shot deal and would be properly tested, unlike the Filter option, which would allow a user to change the code at will, opening further doors to mayhem.

In any case, this discussion does highlight the fact that running a drupal site has many facets, security being a large part, and knowledge is key, but all I can hope is that there isn't a security hole that has gone unnoticed for several releases in the admin interface that would allow any code injection into the 6 lines of code suggested here.

Comment: CAREFUL The PHP option should only be used during development to test options.  It is not a good idea to enable PHP within a active site due to security risks. In such a case, a user could manipulate the site from site input forms etc..

Comment: PHP is certainly a double edged sword, but could you point me to some documentation about security holes opened by using it from within the block administration page options...

Comment: I have been preparing some documentation for the Panels Module and my primary source was Merlinofchaos.  Also, there are a couple paragraphs in "The definitive Guide to Drupal 7 warning about it, and I know I have run across other references to the concern although I have not found any "How to.." articles on it. (Kind of like bomb-making manuals on the internet :).  Actually a question on that subject might be good idea....

Comment: I'm not going to use a solution if it's going to add a potential security issue to the site, any other idea's?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the access seetings for a block to specific roles. By default, the block is accessible for every user with the permission "View published content" (or something like that). To restrict a block for a specific role, change the "Block Settings" / "Access" to "Role" and tick the roles which can see the block.

Comment: I have double checked both block settings and view settings, both of which allow roles to access (which is essentially what you have said), but not to block roles from seeing content.

Comment: Does your user only have the role which has no access? If not, check if probably one of the other roles have access to the block.

Comment: the user would have multiple roles, I ask for a deny because I want it to override an allow, think windows permissions style ;)